# Building form with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am loading in a js file to build a form (I know this isn't standard; this is just for my learning). The contents of that file look like this:

```
window.captor = (function () {
    function Captor () {

    }

    var captor = {
        create: function () {
            return new Captor();
        }
    };

    Captor.prototype.build = function (json) {
        //CREATE BACKDROP WITH CLOSE FUNCTION
        var interstitial = this.backdrop();
        //CREATE DIV CONTAINER
        var container = this.container();
        //CREATE TITLE
        var title = this.setTitle();
        //CREATE CALL TO ACTION
        var cta = this.callToAction();
        //CREATE FORM WITH INPUTS
        var form = this.capture(json);
        interstitial.appendChild(container);
        container.appendChild(title);
        container.appendChild(cta);
        container.appendChild(form);
        document.body.parentNode.appendChild(interstitial);
    };

    Captor.prototype.backdrop = function(){
        var b = document.createElement("div");
        b.setAttribute('style',"position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);z-index: 100;");
        return b;
    };

    Captor.prototype.container = function(){
        var c = document.createElement("div");
        c.setAttribute('style',"position:relative;background:#dedede;min-height:100px;width: 480px;margin: auto;top: 45%;-webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;");
        return c;
    };

    Captor.prototype.setTitle = function(){
        var t = document.createElement("h1");
        var inside = document.createTextNode("Join Our Newsletter");
        t.appendChild(inside);
        return t;
    };

    Captor.prototype.callToAction = function(){
        var cta = document.createElement("p");
        var inside = document.createTextNode("Would you like to find out more about stuff? Join our newsletter!");
        cta.appendChild(inside);
        return cta;
    };

    Captor.prototype.capture = function(json){
        var f = document.createElement("form");
        var hidden = document.createElement("input");
        hidden.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
        f.appendChild(hidden);
        return f;
    };

    return captor;
}());
```

Then after including that file, I call:

```
var n = captor.create();
n.build(window.builder.getj);
```

Where `window.builder.getj` returns a json object (I haven't done anything with that obj, just yet).

So far, the form doesn't build. I'm not sure if anything is getting called. When I look at the console, nothing is output. If I call `var c = captor.create();` it returns `undefined`. If I run `c = captor.create();` it returns `Captor {build: function, backdrop: function, container: function, setTitle: function, callToAction: function…}`.

I feel like I must be missing something, but for the life of me I can't see what it is. How do I get this form to render in the correct way?

Comment: try `document.body.appendChild(...)` rather than using `parentNode` - it's unlikely you'll be wanting to append to the `html` element

Comment: @JamesThorpe I gave that a try. It still doesn't run.

Comment: Any errors logged in the console?  Have you debugged/stepped through the build function? Can you reproduce it on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @JamesThorpe The console says `Uncaught ReferenceError: captor is not defined`. When I create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j18r955c/6/), and load the js as an external resource, it works. If I add the script to the jsfiddle as it is above, it gives that undefined error. I'd prefer to load the js in the script though.